# Split a String, take only 5 items. But limit characters to <20

Tags: regex, google-sheets, spreadsheet

a simple query perhaps.

I use a very useful formula:

```
 =JOIN(replace(A1, find("|", SUBSTITUTE(A1, ", ", "|", 5)), len(A1), ""), "", )
```

...this takes a comma separated cell (may contain x50 strings) and returns only 5, next I'd like to limit the returned strings to those of under 20 characters. Is it possible to incorporate some magic into this formula. I currently use a regex "find and replace" with the value: .{20,} and then delete everything that is over 20 chars. There must be a more beautiful way of doing this?

ie. Cell A1 =

```
here's a string, here's a very long string over 20 chars, string 3, string 4, another string, string 5, another string 7, number 8
```

would become

```
here's a string, string 3, string 4, another string, string 5
```

Also, in formulas... how do you handle errors? If my queried cell only contains 3 strings, and I'm asking for 5 I get an Error, or bad return, what's the trick to handle such an event?

Thanks so much for reading this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=JOIN(", ",ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER(SPLIT(A1,", ",0),LEN(SPLIT(A1,", ",0))<=20),1,5))
```

- SPLIT by delimiter
- FILTER array by LENgth of chars
- ARRAY_CONSTRAIN to constrain the array
- JOIN back the splitted filtered array